# Why is it called hyper-plane?

Tags: geometry, terminology, convention

["In geometry a hyperplane is a subspace of one dimension less than its ambient space."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) However, the Greek prefix hyper- means ["'over', usually implying excess or exaggeration"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hyper). So why do we call a hyperplane a hyperplane, while it actually has *less* dimensions than the original space? Shouldn't it be called hypoplane rather?

Comment: More exactly, ὕπερ means ‘above’.

Comment: "[...] if it actually has less dimensions than the original plane?" The original plane is not the ambient space, it is 2-dimensional Euclidean space. Since positive integers are almost always greater than $3$, hyperplane almost always has dimension greater than the original plane. Hyper serves much better purpose here than hypo would. Anything contained in affine space can't exceed dimension of the space, so hypo would be really redundant.

Comment: What do you mean by "The original plane is not the ambient space"? A 5D space's hyperplane is a 4D plane, and that doesn't have to be 2D Euclidian. Or I am misunderstanding something, which is a totally valid option :D

Comment: We don't call 5-dimensional space a plane. We call it space. A plane is 2-dimensional, and $4>2$, thus, hyperplane of 5-dimensional space justifies its name.

Comment: By definition the hyperplane does generalize to any n. n can be bigger than 4.

Comment: By definition a plane is 2-dimensional. I'm not sure what's the problem?

Comment: "This notion can be used in any general space in which the concept of the dimension of a subspace is defined." So n=4, that's a 4D space, and a hyperplane of this 4D space would be 3D. The definition does contain the relationship to the ambient space.

Comment: @Ennar my problem is, that by definiton a hyperplane *does not* have to be 2-dimensional.

Comment: Your problem is that you are not reading what I wrote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65414/discussion-between-lte-and-ennar).

Comment: Usage is not constrained by etymology. Language is messier than that. The Greek roots of a prefix might be interesting, but they have little direct relevance.

Comment: Given all the discussion, maybe it should have been n-space (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-dimensional_space) to mean the space native to the dimension of the system, so 3-space = the space we are used to. A 3-plane would then be the plane as we are used to it. Consequently, a 2-plane within 2-space would be a line on a sheet of paper in 3-space. Therefore, a 2-plane = 3-line = 4-dot, 2-space = 3-plane, etc. Heck, let's generalize: III_3 = space as we know it. ...

Comment: But to answer/comment the question, I think it just boils down to convention and idiom. One of the hardest part of maths (to us non-mathematicans) is to learn it's idioms and parlance. Just like for example Morse code (which I used to know), the whole nomenclature is not really systematic, at least not accross disciplines within maths. It is parlance that has grown over thousands of years. It's like "How are you?" in US parlance is *not* a request to literally tell the asker how one's feeling. "Handy" in German? Doesn't mean it's _handy_, but means a mobile phone. Etc. Math in that's no except

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When we're working in a general dimension $n$, the general case we're thinking of is that $n>3$. In that case a "hyperplane" has *larger* dimension than the 2-dimensional planes we're used to from solid geometry.

The "plane" is the important part of the word; "hyper" just reminds us that "this is not necessarily your ordinary kind of plane from 3D geometry".

Comment: But i mean, "hypo" would also remind us that it's not our ordinary kind of plane, and would also describe how the hyperplane is less dimensions, than its ambient space.

Comment: @lte__ But "hyper" does not distinguish "hyperplane" from "hyperspace". It distinguishes "hyperplane" from "plane". And, most hyperplanes have _higher_ dimension than ordinary planes.

Comment: But not all... Still this seems like the most appropriate answer, although not as satisfying as I'd like it to be :D

Comment: I would think a "hypoplane" would be a plane with lower dimension than an ordinary plane. But those are just lines in a plane, which we already have names for.

Comment: @MichaelLugo I read it as "typoplane"

Comment: @Ooker: I got "hydroplane".

Comment: @lte__ Naming is not an exact science, but convention. Other names could have been chosen and they would work perfectly fine. Henning's answer tells you the reasons "hyperplane" is used, but you shouldn't expect any answer here to prove that it is the best (or the only) possible name for hyperplanes, because that is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 11):

The "hyper" just refers to the dimension being in excess of the dimension we're used to, for a plane ($2$ dimensions.)

It's the same for "cube" and "hypercube." It's just a way to differentiate a general term from one that is "fossilized" in most people's minds.

Comment: What dimension are we "used to" for a plane?

Comment: Usually, a plane is two-dimensional in our three-dimensional world. So with hyperplane you denote any object that has one dimension less than the original space.

Comment: @lte__ I would venture to say that most people are first taught geometry learning "point, line, plane, space" as in: dimensions $0$, $1$, $2$, and $3$. They learn those well, but don't have words for anything beyond. So when you generalize further, you need to add modifiers...

Comment: But a 2 dimensional plane is still a hyperplane of 3d space, and calling it a hypoplane would also describe how it's got less dimensions than the original one. I understand you need to add modifiers, but a hyperplane doesn't even have to be 4-5+ dimensional... This naming convention seems weird to me for the reasons I've described (~hypoplane would make more sense).

Comment: @lte__ Henning has already pointed out to you the most convincing counterargument, I think. The modifier has nothing to do with its relationship to the dimension of the space. The modifier has to do with its relationship *to planes as most people conceive of them.*

Comment: But by definition a hyperplane is not only 2D. "For instance, a hyperplane of an n-dimensional affine space is a flat subset with dimension n − 1." So we can also talk about 5D hyperplanes in a 6D space. So it's not necessarily 2D.

Comment: @lte__ ... of course a hyperplane isn't necessarily 2D. That's the whole point of the term. It looks a little bit like you're addressing a point I did not posit. I wrote that "plane" alone is usually conceived of as being $2$-dimensional.

Comment: @rschwieb Mathematics with naming conventions to mirror how people conceive of them? That's not what they taught us about math at Uni :D In my experience, maths is ALL ABOUT precise definitions and everything means something specific, not "how people conceive of them".

Comment: @lte__  I think *most* of terminology takes into account how people conceive of things, simply because that is a principle of good communication. That's why one would call something a "quasi-Frobenius ring" because it is "nearly Frobenius."  I don't really know how else to respond to your comment, if you are seriously suggesting that choice of terms should have nothing to do with how language is actually used.

Comment: Nowhere did I say they've got NOTHING to do with it. I said they're mostly logical and meaningful. quasi-Frobenius ring is called that because it's nearly Frobenius. Exactly. It has meaning. It's not about how people perceive it's almost the same, it's more about how mathematically it's almost the same. But you wouldn't call a Bernoulli-distribution quasi-normal just because their graphs look roughly the same. That's what I mean by "how humans conceive" stuff.

Comment: @lte__ Right, I can agree with that. I was just trying to express natural language has a heavy influence on terms, and I didn't intend to imply that you absolutely excluded it from consideration. And Henning and I both showed you the logic in the choice of hyper over hypo :) When naming objects with more dimensions than a regular plane, it doesn't make sense to call it "less than a plane."

Comment: It might make sense to nickname subspaces as "hypospaces," but nobody probably does that because we already *have* "subspace."  Then again, "hyperspace" does not mean "space that contains another space," it mostly means "space with more dimensions than regular space," so my idea for hypospace isn't that useful either, since it doesn't fit the analogy well.